# Maths exam question on consecutive Pythagoras triplets

Tags: triangles

Our 13 year old daughter brought home this maths question that she was asked in a "maths challenge" last week:

*Q. The values of the adjacent and opposite sides in a right angle triangle of lengths 3, 4, 5 are consecutive. Obtain another triangle with consecutive adjacent and opposite sides having values between 500 and 1000.*

My wife and I spent two hours trying to figure it out before we gave up. The teacher provided the solution (696, 697, 985) but could not explain how to obtain it. Searching on internet we can see solutions to this but none of them that we would expect even a very clever 13 year old to know. Are we missing something obvious?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: There is a systematic way to search all the solutions based on solutions to the Pell-equation, but I would not consider this to be easy. I think, I have answered this question here, but I could not yet find my answer.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes, I have come across the Pell equation but I would not expect a kid this age to know or derive it. The maths challenge was aimed at 13 year olds from all the schools in our town. All my daughter has been taught is Pythagoras' theorem. I suppose that some of the other schools may have been taught the method for calculating triplets in general (m^2 +n^2; 2mn; m^2-n^2) but knowing this alone does not make the question much easier for them to figure out. I cannot believe they are expected to just plug numbers in as it would take hours.

Comment: Is this exercise be expected to be solved by hand ? Is a table calculator allowed ? Perhaps, it is expected that a computer program is written. In any case, I do not think that there is an "easy" solution.

Comment: Another (not very likely) possibility is that the asker underestimated the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: Calculator allowed. It was not a computing exercise. This question is from a 1 hour paper with a total of 5 questions. I spent about 10 minutes on each of the other questions.

Comment: I will contact the organisation running the challenge. Maybe they mixed the question up with one from a university exam by mistake :-)

Comment: It was a mock test using the question from last year. You can see it at this link (3 ESO paper, Question 2). It is in Spanish, but should be clear from the context. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eqW7eU0hiRkehrX3Vkis1CojKr-n5dbL

Comment: Note that making the one leg and the hypotenuse consecutive is a much simpler exercise, and one I could expect clever 13-year-olds to solve within 10 minutes.

Comment: I would tell the teacher not to use terminology such as  " adjacent sides" and "opposite sides" when talking of triangles

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I just noticed as well this confusing formulation : Sides in a triangle are not "opposite" !

Comment: $a^2+(a+1)^2=b^2\implies (2a+1)^2+1=2b^2. $ By trial and error, this holds when $a=20.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Sure that the implication in your last comment is valid ?

Comment: @Peter. Typo. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: The words "adjacent" and "opposite" are the ones I used when translating. In the  original Spanish question they use the word "catetos" which is unambiguous and basically means "the two shorter sides", which I suppose I could have said instead.

Comment: The teacher could not explain how to find the (only) solution , but expected the $13$ year old kids to find it ?

Comment: @Peter The terms opposite and adjacent refer to an acute angle in the Pythagorean triple and translate loosely to sine and cosine.

Answer (score 3):

The question, of course, is down to the following.

Let $a>0$ be a natural number. When is
$$
a^2+(a+1)^2=2a^2+2a+1=b^2
$$
for some other natural number $b$?

The question doesn't seem suitable for school kids, except possibly the very brightest ones, *given the fact (that I haven't checked) that the next solution is for $a=696$*.

There's a standard way to obtain Pythagorean triples using analytic geometry. In fact Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ are essentially in one-to-one correspondence with points on the circle $C:x^2+y^2=1$ with both coordinates rational. The association is
$$
(a,b,c)\longleftrightarrow\left(\frac ac,\frac bc\right)\in C.
$$
Thus we can parametrize Pythagorean triples systematically, just take the generic line $y=t(x-1)$ through $(1,0)\in C$ and the second point of intersection $P_t$ will have both coordinates in $\Bbb Q$ exactly when $t\in\Bbb Q$. In fact the coordinates of the second intersection point are easily obtained:
$$
P_t=\left(\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1},\frac{2t}{t^2+1}\right)
$$
(parameter $t$ renormalized so to have the coordinates both positive when $t>0$). Yet doesn't seem to be a trivial task to answer the question using this parametrization.

It's worth noting that the problem would be much easier if we would ask that the difference of length between the hypothenuse and one of the sides be $1$, as in the case $(5,12,13)$.

Indeed one would have to check when
$$
c^2-b^2=(c+b)(c-b)=c+b=2b+1\qquad\qquad\qquad(*)
$$
is a square and that is essentialy a trivial task. For instance one gets in a few seconds of a systematic search the triples $(7,24,25)$, $(9,40,41)$ and so on.

In fact, as even a 13 years old may find soon, just **every** odd number, not just the squares, is a sum of two consecutive numbers.

Comment: @Peter: just take any odd square, say $169=13^2$. Then write $169=84+85$ (consecutive numbers). Thus $(13,84,85)$ is Pythagorean.

Comment: OK, easy enough, but I miss the argument that we can be sure that $$13^2+84^2=85^2$$ based on this representation.

Comment: OK, you worked it out, sorry. What remains to show however, that we do not miss a solution.

Comment: @Peter, it's the displayed line labelled $(*)$ in my post

Comment: By the way, the smallest solutions for the given problem are $3,20,119,696$

Comment: $20^2+21^2=29^2$.

Comment: (+1) for mentioning and analyzing the easier case.

Comment: @Peter, ah, ok $20$. That's a way smaller solution than the one provided by the teacher. Still, who would expect a 13 years old kid to go over some 20 trials before getting an answer?

Comment: @AndreaMori I agree

Comment: @AndreaMori. I agree, somewhat. If you notice that  $a^2 +(a+1)^2=b^2$ implies that  $b$ is odd, checking with odd $b\ge 7$ gets  success on the $12$th case $b=29.$

Answer (score 2):

$x^2+(x+1)^2=y^2 \implies (x+1)^2 = (y+x)(y-x)$

Note that $a=y+x$ and $b=y-x$ gives $x={a-b\over 2}$ and the equation becomes $(a-b+2)^2=4ab$

$2x^2 > 500^2$, $2(x+1)^2 < 1000^2\implies x \geq 354$ and $x \leq 706$ so $1706\geq a\geq 854$ and $646 \geq b\geq 0$

Let $gcd(a,b)=k$ then $(a_1k-b_1k+2)^2=4a_1b_1k^2$ meaning $k^2 \mid (a_1k-b_1k+2)^2$ meaning $k \mid a_1k-b_1k+2$ meaning $k \mid 2$.

($1$) $k=1$ then $(a-b+2)^2=4ab$ where $a,b$ are coprime and are both square numbers.
 $42^2>1706\geq a\geq 854>29^2$ and $26^2>646 \geq b\geq 0$ means there are only $12$ values of $a$ to be checked. Furthermore $a$ cannot be even because if so then $b$ is odd to be coprime with $a$ and the left side becomes odd. So we  only needs to check $6$ values of $a$.

Expand equation $b^2-2(3a+2)b+(a+2)^2=0$, $\Delta = 32a(a+1)$ is a square number or simply ${a+1\over 2}$ is a square number.

Plug in values $a=31^2,33^2,...,41^2$ and check ${a+1\over 2}$ we get only one pair ($a=41^2, b=17^2$), this correspond to the poster's $x=696$

($2$) $k=2$ then $(a_1-b_1+1)^2=16a_1b_1$, thus $a_1, b_1$ are both square numbers. $20^2<427\leq a_1\leq853<30^2, $$b_1 \leq 323<18^2$

Expand equation ${b_1}^2-2(9a_1+1)b_1+(a_1+1)^2=0$, $\Delta = 64a_1(5a_1+1)$ is a square number or simply $5a+1$ is a square number.

This time we have $9$ values of $a_1$ to check from $21$ to $29$. However none of the values produce an integral $b_1$. As a result $x=696$, given by the poster, is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain where you get the 3rd line from: 2x^2 > 500^2. The question says x > 500, so x^2 > 500^2, so why is it multiplied by 2?

Comment: @user1682654 The question says $y>500$ and $y^2 > 2x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

All Pythagorean triples where $\space B-A=\pm1\space$ can be generated using adjacent $\space (k,m)\space$
[Pell numbers](https://oeis.org/search?q=pell+numbers&sort=&language=&go=Search)
$\big\{0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169,\cdots\big\}$
and Euclid's formula here shown as
$\quad A=m^2-k^2,\space B=2mk,\space C=m^2+k^2\quad$ and these numbers may be generated using $$m=k+\sqrt{2k^2+(-1)^k}$$

The resulting triples are

\begin{align*}
F(2,1)&=(3,4,5)\\
F(5,2)&=(21,20,29)\\
F(12,5)&=(119,120,169)\\
F(29,12)&=(697,696,985)\\
F(70,29)&=(4059,4060,5741)\\
F(169,70)&=(23661,23660,33461)\\
&\space\vdots
\end{align*}

The process is simpler for adjacent sides $\space(B,C).\space$ In all primitive Pythagorean triples,
$\space C-B=(2x-1)^2, x\in\mathbb{N}\space$ and this is reflected in the formula:
\begin{align*}
A&=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\ 
B&=         &&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
C&=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\space
\end{align*}
Using this formula,
$\quad n=1\iff C-B=1\quad$ and the formula reduces to

$$A=2k+1\quad B=2 k^2+2k\quad C=2 k^2 + 2 k + 1$$

which generates

$(3,4,5)\quad( 5,12,13)\quad (7,24,25)\quad (9,40,41)\quad (11,60,61)\quad (13,84,85)\quad\cdots $